# How To Call Mobile Phone Number in iOS

Tags: objective-c, ios7, xcode5

My Simple Problem is to make a call on particular mobile number in iOS App using Objective C Code for example if i have a number like "8001022220" without using [[[UIApplication]sharedApplication] openurl[nsurl urlwithstring@"telpnonenimber"]];

I want to do real world calling like we do usually

Thanks in advance and help would be appreciated and really help full for me.

Answer (score 0):

There are only two ways to initiate a call in iOS; either with an embedded `HTML` link or a native app URL string (as in your example):

```
<a href="tel:1-408-555-5555">1-408-555-5555</a>
```

...or...

```
tel:1-408-555-5555
```

Unfortunately, you can't actually "dial" a person using the native voice capabilities of the phone *within* your app, plain and simple.

[Reference documentation here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/PhoneLinks/PhoneLinks.html).

Answer (score 0):

```
NSURL *URL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"tel://900-3440-567"];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:URL];
```

This will work for you.